# How to create cred (neopop) like button in react-native

Tags: android, css, ios, reactjs, react-native

[image]

Designing elevated effect, I used `skewY:45deg` but it's not working on Android and working on the web. Is there any workaround for creating this kind of design?

styles reference

```js
buttonEdgeRight: {
  backgroundColor: disabled
    ? colorConfig?.disabledColors?.edgeColors?.right ?? "transparent"
    : colorConfig?.edgeColors?.right ?? "transparent",
  height:
    Platform.OS === "web"
      ? `calc(100% - ${EDGEWIDTH}px)`
      : layout.height - EDGEWIDTH / 2,
  right: 0,
  top: 0,
  transform: getTransform([{ translateZ: 0 }, { skewY: "45deg" }]),
  width: EDGEWIDTH,
  zIndex: 2,
},
buttonEdgeRightPressed: {
  transform:
    disabled || shouldNotMoveBottomEdge(elevationDirection)
      ? [{ skewY: `${SKEW_ANGLE}deg` }]
      : getTransform([
        { translateX: EDGEWIDTH },
        { translateY: EDGEWIDTH },
        { translateZ: 0 },
        { skewY: `${SKEW_ANGLE}deg` },
      ]),
},
```

Comment: You can use CardView to create button.

Comment: I want recreate this design in react native @PratikSatani   https://playground.cred.club/?path=/docs/components-button--sample-button

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have more idea about it.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion @PratikSatani but we need same that kind effect

Comment: May be this will help you: https://github.com/efoken/neopop-react-native

Comment: He also did the same.... we have bug in react native itself for skew transform https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27649